# Using KeyVaultClient through a proxy

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-keyvault

Currently I'm using Azure KeyVault during startup to load some configuration like this:

```
configBuilder
    .AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultConfigSection.Vault, GetKeyVaultClient(clientConfigSection, keyVaultConfigSection), new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager())
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

private static KeyVaultClient GetKeyVaultClient(ClientConfigSection clientConfigSection, KeyVaultConfigSection keyVaultConfigSection)
{
    HttpClient httpClient = null;

    //proxy
    if (!CustomEnvironment.NotProductionEnvironment())
    {
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            Proxy = new WebProxy(keyVaultConfigSection.Proxy),
            UseProxy = true
        };
        httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
    }

    return new KeyVaultClient(async (authority, resource, scope) =>
        {
            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
            var clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientConfigSection.ClientId, clientConfigSection.ClientSecret);
            var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCred);
            if (result == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to retrieve access token for Key Vault");
            return result.AccessToken;
        }, httpClient ?? new HttpClient()
    );
}
```

This works fine when I'm not in production environment.
But in our production environment keyvault is blocked so we have to go through a proxy.

But when running the code I get this error: `Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Models.KeyVaultErrorException: 'Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest''`

Have anyone done this before and can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it has not been fixed, and here is the [workaround](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/4404#issuecomment-436039941).

1.Referenced `System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler` Nuget package to get access to WinHttpHandler in .NET Core.

2.Created a new MyKeyVaultCredential that inherits from KeyVaultCredential and overrides `ProcessHttpRequestAsync` method

```
public override async Task ProcessHttpRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 {
     if (request == null)
     {
         throw new ArgumentNullException("request");
     }

     var accessToken = await PreAuthenticate(request.RequestUri).ConfigureAwait(false);
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
         request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
     else
     {
         var httpClientHandler = new WinHttpHandler()
         {
             WindowsProxyUsePolicy = WindowsProxyUsePolicy.UseCustomProxy,
             Proxy = new MyWebProxy(configuration),
             SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120),
             ReceiveDataTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120),
             ReceiveHeadersTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120),
         };
```

3.When I instantiated the KeyVaultService, I had to provide WinHttpHandler with my proxy and my new key vault credential instance.

```
var httpClientHandler = new WinHttpHandler()
     {
         WindowsProxyUsePolicy = WindowsProxyUsePolicy.UseCustomProxy,
         Proxy = new MyWebProxy(configuration),
         SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120),
         ReceiveDataTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120),
         ReceiveHeadersTimeout= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120),
     };

     var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);

     client = new KeyVaultClient(new  MyKeyVaultCredential(configuration, GetToken), httpClient)
```

Hope this helps.